# CUDA Shared Memory not exclusive to block while debugging

Tags: cuda, nsight, gpu-shared-memory

Basically, I am having a difficult time understand exactly what is going wrong here.

Shared memory does not appear to be behaving in a block exclusive manner while debugging.  When running the code normally, nothing is printed.  However, if I attempt to debug it, shared memory is shared between blocks and the print statement is reached.

This is an example, obviously this isn't terribly useful code, but it reproduces the issue on my system.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is this a bug or expected behavior from the debugger?

```
__global__ 
void test()
{
    __shared__ int result[1];
    if (blockIdx.x == 0 && blockIdx.y == 0 && blockIdx.z == 0)
        result[0] = 4444;
    else
    {
        if (result[0] == 4444)
            printf("This should never print if shared memory is unique\n");
    }
}
```

And to launch it:

```
test<<<dim3(8,8,1), dim3(8,8,1)>>>();
```

It is also entirely possible that I have completely misunderstood shared memory.

Thanks for the help.

**Other Information:**
I am using a GTX 460. `compute_20` and `sm_20` are set for the project.  I am writing the code in Visual Studio 2010 using Nsight 3.0 preview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a subtle but important difference between

> shared memory is shared between blocks and the print statement is
>   reached

and

> shared memory is re-used by successive blocks and the print statement is
>   reached

You are assuming the former, but the latter is what is really happening.

Your code, with the exception of the first block, is reading from uninitialised memory. That, in itself, is undefined behaviour. C++ (and CUDA) don't guarantee that statically declared memory is set to any value when it either comes into, or goes out of scope. You can't expect that `result` wouldn't have a value of 4444, especially when it is probably stored in the same shared scratch space as a previous block which may have set it to a value of 4444.

The entire premise of the code and this question are flawed and you should draw no conclusions from the result you see other that undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Ah, this makes perfect sense.  

I guess I was confused since it seems to usually start at 0 when starting a kernel call.  I should not have assumed that it was guaranteed to do that.  Thanks for the explanation!